# jQuery iterate table rows using table object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

am working on Drag & Drop table rows and updating the order in Database.

I wrote a generic function for all the tables like in attachment. Please suggest how to iterate table rows from the table object. And also please advise any useful plug-ins to implement Drag & Drop feature.

Error Message: **Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object] > tbody > tr**
Here is the fiddler link: https://jsfiddle.net/22yLakr3/5/

```
$("table").sortable({
            items: "tr",
            cursor: 'move',
            opacity: 0.6,
            update: function () {
                var abc = $(this);
                $(abc + ' > tbody > tr').each(function () {                      
                   var id = $(this).attr('data-k');                 
                });

            }
        });
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure why this one is down voted.

Comment: It is a typo error.. But After changing tobody to tbody also it is not working. It is treating abc as object. Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object] > tbody > tr

Comment: can you provide a fiddle ?

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi: Updated question with Fiddler link  and Error Message. Thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

You have two points to take care of:

the first is: why to loop inside the update events? If you need to take the data-k of current updated element the solution is different

the second is: if you need to loop on each row you cannot use an object as a selector.

In the following (see the remarks in the update event function):

```js
$(function () {
  $("table").sortable({
    items: "tr",
    cursor: 'move',
    opacity: 0.6,
    update: function (event, ui) {
      // on update you may take the data-k atribute value simply:
      var lDataK = ui.item.data('k');


      // If instead on update (triggered when the user stopped sorting and 
      // the DOM position has changed)
      // you need to look for all rows you need to write:
      $(this).find('tbody > tr').each(function (index, element) {
        var id = element.getAttribute('data-k');
        // now you can use this value
      });

    }
  });
});
```

Comment: "data-k" is the Id column in DB(primary key). I was thinking to update the order based on Ids order in table(after drag & drop). Will try to use your solution and keep in mind your suggestions. Thank you.